# Updated title of arxiv not recognised by Google Scholar?

Tags: arxiv, google-scholar

I submitted a paper to a journal and one of the referees suggested to slightly change the title of the paper. The paper was already posted on arxiv. I have updated the paper on arxiv after the revision, but this update is not recognised by Google Scholar. The main problem with this is that Google Scholar is not detecting the new citations to the arxiv paper since the new citations use the new title.

Any suggestions on how to solve this issue?

**Update:** I updated the arxiv version 2 months ago but Google Scholar does not detect it. It detects new papers that cite my manuscript, but not the updated arxiv.

**Disclaimer.** I am aware of the following questions, but they are related to different issues.

[Submitted to arXiv with a different title. How to make Google understand this is the same paper?](https://academia.stackexchange.com/q/31800)

[Do all versions of an arXiv paper appear in Google Scholar?](https://academia.stackexchange.com/q/20172)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Google Scholar should (relatively soon) detect both versions, at which point it will likely list them separately.  Once both versions are showing up in your profile, you can merge them together.  Select the check-boxes next to both publications, and a "Merge" button should appear amongst the buttons up at the top of the list.  During the merge process, you can tell it which version is the "best" version, and it will use the information for that version as the source for its title, authorship, etc.

Comment: I am not sure if the detection is going to happen at all since I updated the arxiv paper 2 months ago, but it doesn't appear in Google Scholar. What you suggest is what I would also expect to happen.

Comment: Per one of your linked questions, check to see if Google Scholar's "old" version is pointing to the new one or not.  If it is, then you can edit the citation information in Google Scholar.  If not, then give it another month or so (Scholar can be pretty random in its update time), and then report it as an indexing bug if it still hasn't updated.  Don't panic, though, because citation tracking is a long game, not a short one.

Comment: Indeed, the "old" version redirects to the new arxiv version. Thanks for your comments. I'll be patient.

Comment: Any update on this? My arXiv title was updated to reflect the published title, but 6 months later Google Scholar has not updated the arXiv title (even though it links to the new version).

Comment: it's not a "relatively soon", since they only reindex their sources [twice yearly](https://scholar.google.com/intl/en/scholar/inclusion.html#troubleshooting).

Answer (score 6):

You can change the citation info by clicking the Edit button in the top-right corner:

[image: Google Scholar]

Comment: But then then the link between GS and arxiv paper gets broken

Answer (score 3):

Google Scholar usually first indexes papers appearing within 7-14 days of their original announcement in arXiv, and then again within 2-3 days for minor tweaks that might have occurred after announcement. Any subsequent replacements or other metadata changes will appear in Google Scholar during their twice-yearly full system reindex, where they re-harvest all their data sources (details are at item number 1 in [their documentation](https://scholar.google.com/intl/en/scholar/inclusion.html#troubleshooting)). Typically these indices occur in January and July. No prior notice is given to arXiv that they are occurring, so arXiv cannot provide you with specifics regarding dates for the next harvest.

Comment: I previously uploaded the v1 paper version on arXiv. However, when it was published, the paper's title did not match the title on arXiv. This resulted in my citations on arXiv v1 not being associated with published papers. I've uploaded the v2 version on arXiv with a title that matches the published paper. From your explanation, next January Google Scholar will replace the indexed arXiv v1 with v2 and associate citations with v2 and the published version, correct?

Comment: @XuesongYe as we have been informed by the Google Scholar team, yes.