# How to show patents in my google scholar profile?

Tags: google-scholar, patents

I have a Google Scholar profile where my conference papers are located.
Google automatically added one, while I had to manually add another.
See https://scholar.google.com/citations?user=ZveOfZYAAAAJ&hl=it

I'm also inventor for a few patents that appear on Google Patent.
See https://patents.google.com/?inventor=alberto+soragna&language=ENGLISH

I wonder why Google does not show the patents automatically in my Scholar profile. I see several users that have both papers and patents there.

BTW since a couple of weeks I also have a personal website where I listed the above publications (patents included), as suggested by Google scholar guidelines.

Thank you

Comment: https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/41412/updated-title-of-arxiv-not-recognised-by-google-scholar

Answer (score 4):

"+" and "Add article groups" allowed me to add some of my patents **including** their citations.  Nicole's suggestion ("Add article manually") misses citations, and "Add articles" seems not to find patents.  Google's UI is not up to Google's usual standards here.

I also changed "Configure article updates" to "Don't automatically update my profile."  I am pretty sure the patents I added had been in my profile previously, and most likely Google's "auto update" had deleted them.

Answer (score 3):

If a patent or any other publication is missing from your Google scholar profile, go to your profile and click the + icon at the top of your list of publications and select "Add article manually".  You'll get a popup with tabs across the top for various kinds of publications.  Click "Patent" and fill in the details.

If Google lists a publication that's not yours (it happens!), click the checkbox next to it, then Delete.

Comment: Super helpful response; as per Ulrich's answer, the manual addition was needed for patents specifically.

Answer (score 1):

Your patents published on 13 August and 3 September 2020, respectively. I suspect Google Scholar will automatically add them soon.