# Google scholar doesn't index the peer reviewed version of my publication, but only the ArXiv version

Tags: publications, arxiv, google-scholar

I have submitted a version of my manuscript to the arXiv (https://arxiv.org/abs/2104.02340) and it was indexed within days on Google Scholar (https://scholar.google.co.uk/citations?view_op=view_citation&hl=en&user=PsyBqUAAAAAJ&sortby=pubdate&citation_for_view=PsyBqUAAAAAJ:hMod-77fHWUC).

After a few months, the manuscript was peer-reviewed and published in ACS Applied Electronic Materials (https://doi.org/10.1021/acsaelm.1c00491). However, the peer-reviewed version of my publication is not being indexed in Google Scholar. It appears at the top of the list when I do a "normal" Google search, but it doesn't appear when I do a Google Scholar search.

I have encountered the exact same issue with another paper (https://arxiv.org/abs/2104.00364) which was published in Wiley Advanced Electronic Materials (https://doi.org/10.1002/aelm.202100419) and is not being indexed in Google Scholar.

I have thought about adding the paper manually to my profile with the correct publisher name, but the citations for that paper will continue to appear on the ArXiv version in Google Scholar, even though the references are addressing the peer-reviewed version.

Disclaimer: I am aware of the following question, but it is related to a different issue. The question hasn't been resolved anyways.

[Updated title of arxiv not recognised by Google Scholar?](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/41412/updated-title-of-arxiv-not-recognised-by-google-scholar)

Comment: Thanks Sursula for your response. Unfortunately, this does not answer my question because the published version (in ACS Applied Electronic Materials) is not being indexed in my case.

Comment: This question has been incorrectly flagged as duplicate. The flagged duplicate is an entirely different question. (Also, the accepted answer to that question was to change the title of the referenced paper)